# Searching for Open source employees AI face check software

Tags: open-source, artificial-intelligence, computer-vision, face-recognition

I have one request from the industry (mining industry), for having one Employee Check In & Out by using the AI  face detection methods.

So I have googled and found some of ready AI face detection codes and found some useful codes like gathered [here](https://github.com/Startup-Data/Mining-face-detection-Employee-Check-In-Out/tree/main/AI_part):

[image]

But I asked here to find out about the open source ready software for  Employee Check  by face detection.

If not, and be possible, I like to have some comment about which open source android application is good ([like said here](https://www.goodfirms.co/blog/best-free-open-source-attendance-tracking-software)), to add the above code into it and change it to one face detection Employee Check In & Out?

Thanks.